# React-native Android Emulator needs to turn on debugger mode

Tags: javascript, react-native

**Why I need to turn Debugger mode on for react-native app when I do 
 run it  in Android emulator in React-Native App ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When your app foreground on the emulator, press `ctrl+m` at the same time. Then open menu, choose it `Debug js remotely`.
Open browser this link `http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui`. Port number can be different.

Answer (score 1):

Press cmd+m and it will show the options, then select "Debug" at the bottom

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).